# Why are the View elements disabling interactive elements?

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, view, constraints

I am just playing a bit with the constraints and auto layout within iOs. I made up a design which caused the interactive elements (except for the buttons) to be disabled. I cannot toggle them.

First they were working, but then I applied a few Views and constraints... I colored the Views underneath the disabled elements. So programmatically I did not make a change.

[image]

What did I do wrong?

**EDIT**

Here the constraints of the back and save button:
[image]

Comment: Check if any other view is not covering the element on which you want to receive an event.

Comment: I turned all views their background into a visible color.

Comment: Show the constraints that you have applied. Check the constraints of the UIView containing Back and Save buttons. It might be covering the other views.

Comment: You can not toggle them on which device/simulator?

Comment: I cannot toggle them with an iPhone 8 and 8+.

Comment: The little Red arrow-circle-icon means you have a conflict with your constraints. That isn't necessarily the reason you cannot interact with objects, but it certainly could be related. See if you can fix your constraint conflicts. Also, when your app is running, use the Debug View Hierarchy feature in Xcode to double-check the elements and make sure nothing is covering anything, and that nothing has, for example, a height of Zero but not clipping its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr @DonMag pointed me at the right thing:

> The little Red arrow-circle-icon means you have a conflict with your constraints. That isn't necessarily the reason you cannot interact with objects, but it certainly could be related.

The little Red arrow-circle-icon pointed me at a missing constraint for the height of the underlying elements view. Once I set the height of the View, the elements where enabled again.